# A blank page holding for several seconds if Cloudflare enabled

Tags: cdn, cloudflare

Recently I fully use the Cloudflare CDN for my domain. I point my namesever to Cloudflare and enable it with SSL/TLS encryption in Full mode. I found there is a blank page when I start loading the page and then all contents show up immediately. It let some visitors think there is a problem when loading the page in the first few seconds of time. I do the speed testing and get the result as the attached screenshot. Do anyone can help to explain what the meaning for this testing and how can I minimize the time before the visitors to my website see content in 2.2 seconds? Does this 2.2 seconds be the reason of the blank page loading time? How can I improve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact domain, a number of things can be at play.

1. Long First Byte Times - If the first byte time of a server is long, users will be seeing the white screen for a while.
2. Poor JavaScript Integration - JavaScript can manipulate the DOM and block images, and other things from loading.
3. Lots of synchronous requests - Even with HTTP2 the browser can only make so many requests in parallel.  If there are lots of images, css, and js requests, then the page would appear white while those load.

Providing the precise URL could help shed light on what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Gerg, providing the URL is the best way to solicit useful feedback to rapidly resolve such issues.

You mentioned that after using Cloudflare you noticed there's a blank page when the content first loads, is it possible this blank page existed previously as well and was noticed only with Cloudflare. Could you try switching away from Cloudflare, by setting the DNS with your hosting provider directly to see if that's the culprit.

You could also disable the proxying behavior of Cloudflare and use it purely as a DNS, as described [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/reference/proxied-dns-records/). Do note this removes a lot of the valuable features and security that make Cloudflare special, so don't forget to turn the proxy on after the experiment.

However, I strongly believe there are other factors at play causing the high first contentful paint. Some general steps to follow could be:

1. Prioritize above-the-fold content.
2. Load below-the-fold images and data lazily.
3. Analyze the [Lighthouse report](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/) (you can use the Chrome Browser or the CLI for both mobile and Desktop).
4. Reduce your DOM size
5. Install a core web vitals optimization plugin. ...
6. Reduce server response time. ...
7. Eliminate render-blocking resources. ...
8. Optimize your CSS structure. ...
9. Avoid JavaScript-dependent elements above the fold. ...
10. Avoid lazy loading images above the fold. ...
11. Optimize and compress images.

Here's an excellent resource from [Jetpack](https://jetpack.com/blog/wordpress-first-contentful-paint/) throwing more light on the points mentioned above.